# MySQL query "\"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'd like to query all user_questions where a question ends with a '\'.

I tried the following but the none of them seem to work. All of them return empty results.

```
select * from user_question where question like "%\\"

select * from user_questions where question like "%[\]"

select * from user_questions where question like "%\\\\"

select * from user_questions where question like "%[\\]"
```

I am using mysql workbench 6.0.7

[mysql - How to handle query search with special characters /(forward slash) and \(backslash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490325/mysql-how-to-handle-query-search-with-special-characters-forward-slash-and)

Comment: Your 3rd query is the correct one.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9ceb7/1

Comment: Does workbench use `"\"` as a the end symbol for SQL statements?

Comment: @RocketHazmat but it doesn't seem to work on mysql workbench.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user_questions where question like "%\\\\"
```

This one should work, tested it myself.

Comment: It gives a syntax error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"%\\\"' at line 1

Comment: Wow, indeed 4 to be exact.. I edited multiple times because it wasn't how I wanted it.. and now it all changed weird. Caused by ctrlk+k on last edit, sorry boys :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
select *
from user_question
where right(question, 1) = '\\';
```