# Concatenating a SQL string query in a JSP file

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I have a html page that allows users to enter specific search terms to query the database I've created. The problem I'm having is that when I pass the string to execute as a sql query, it is not wrapping the query in single quotes which is needed to search for a string match in a sql database. Here is the code I have currently:

```
//Create a statement for the sql queries  
java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

//Get results from queries entered  
String result_event_name = request.getParameter("event_name");

//Create query string   
String sqlQuery_event  = "SELECT event_name FROM event where event_name = " + "\'" + result_event_name + "\'";

//execute query  
java.sql.ResultSet rs_event = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery_event);`
```

This is the error I get:

```
SQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input Position: 49
```

I tried using prepare statement -- returns same error
I tried the query without escaping -- returns same error
I tried with no single quotes -- returns same error

Comment: try String sqlQuery_event  = "SELECT event_name FROM event where event_name = " + "\\'" + result_event_name + "\\'";

Comment: Why using something which is deprecated, just avoid writting writting codes inside JSP use templating instead.

Comment: Also you might want to learn about prepared statements to prevent [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The single quote `'` only needs escaping once LIKE `'%\'%'`
2. But to query backslash `\` you need to double escape to LIKE `'%\\\\%'`
3. If you wanted to query backslash+singlequote `\'` then LIKE `'%\\\\\'%'`
   (with 5 backslashes)

[Explanation Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) excerpt:

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”.
>   To search for “\”, specify it as “\”; this is because the backslashes
>   are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is
>   made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Credit goes to [xchiltonx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422486/xchiltonx)

### Resource Link:

[mysql - How to handle query search with special characters /(forward slash) and \(backslash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490325/mysql-how-to-handle-query-search-with-special-characters-forward-slash-and)