# Search HTML using LIKE Operator in Database MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb

I have stored some html in my database, for example:

```
ID | Data
1  | <a href=\"link\" class=\"someclass\" id=\"id_10923074\"><h3 class=\"class1 class2\"><\/h3><br \/><div class=\"clearfix\"><\/div><\/a>
2  | <a href=\"lin2\" class=\"someclass\" id=\"id_10923075\"><h3 class=\"class1 class2\">some text<\/h3><br \/><div class=\"clearfix\"><\/div><\/a>
```

Now, I would like to query an invalid records which doesn't contain text in the h3, which is row 1.

I have tried many queries, some are bellow:

```
SELECT `mytable`.* FROM `mytable` WHERE (Data LIKE '%<h3 class=\"class1 class2\"><\/h3>%')

SELECT `mytable`.* FROM `mytable` WHERE (Data LIKE '%h3 class="class1 class2"></h3%')

SELECT `mytable`.* FROM `mytable` WHERE (Data LIKE '"%class1 class2%"')

SELECT `mytable`.* FROM `mytable` WHERE (Data LIKE '%<h3 class=\"class1 class2\">%')
```

What am I missing here? I have been checking many questions here but cannot find any solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it simply not returning anything, or is it actually doing a sql error?

Comment: Its simply not returning any thing, it says zero rows found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310845/3310343):

So the trick is to double escape ONLY the backslash, for string escapes only a single escape is needed.

For example

```
The single quote ' only needs escaping once LIKE '%\'%'
But to query backslash \ you need to double escape to LIKE '%\\\\%'
If you wanted to query backslash+singlequote \' then LIKE '%\\\\\'%' (with 5 backslashes)
```

Explanation Source excerpt:

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”.
>   To search for “\”, specify it as “\”; this is because the backslashes
>   are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is
>   made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Correct Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (Data LIKE '%<h3 class=\\\\"class1 class2\\\\"><\\\\/h3>%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as expected. See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba3554/2):

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (Data LIKE '%<h3 class=\"class1 class2\"><\/h3>%')
```

Your issue most likely lies with your quoting. Ensure you are escaping backslashes (`\`) and quotes (`"`) properly in your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying direcly running in mysql as well, for example: 

SELECT `mytable`.* FROM `mytable` WHERE (Data LIKE '%<h3 class=\"class1 class2\">%') doesn't work in my mysql directly, but in your sqlfiddle it works, any ideas?

Comment: Does your data contain physical backlashes in the database? If yes, then ensure you're passing `\\\"` to match for both a backslash, and a quote.

Comment: Yes, data originally looks like how I showed in question. the slashes are physical in database. I have tried \\\" but no success :(

Comment: There is no php code, I am just querying using mysql directly now so I can delete the invalid records.

Answer (score 0):

To find rows where `Data` has at least one `<h3>` (with or without any attributes such as `class=`) with no text before `</h3>`:

```
WHERE Data REGEXP '<h3[^>]*></h3>'
```

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @FrankerZ - "No" meaning what?  Fails to find empty h3s?  Or fails to ignore empty h3s?  Give an example.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it doesn't work either, returns zero rows.

Comment: @M3Dev - Strange.  I changed FrankerZ's sqlfiddle to use my REGEXP, and I got one row.