# MySql , Select with special Character

Tags: mysql, sql

so i have a table with this data, but when i query "select * from assetprofile WHERE
description1='(1) GENSET\FOR ATM' ", it shows nothing . any help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6e0D.png)

Comment: Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310845/4274040)

Answer (score 0):

Try use IN operator:

```
SELECT * from assetprofile WHERE description1 IN ('(1) GENSET\FOR ATM')
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample data does not have a space between the parentheses and GET, but your query does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the string using `QUOTE` function:

```
SELECT * FROM assetprofile WHERE description1 = QUOTE('(1) GENSET\FOR ATM');
```