# Laravel query builder raw case

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to use a case control structure in a Laravel.I can not for the life of me get the required 'blueberry' result even though there are muffins with the 'App\Models\blueberrymuffin' type in the database.

```
$muffintype=DB::table('muffins')
->select(
DB::raw"(CASE muffin_type WHEN 'App\Models\blueberrymuffin' THEN 'Blueberry' END)" ))->get();
```

I don't think it is my syntax since when I test this out it works.

```
$muffintype=DB::table('muffins')
->select(
DB::raw"(CASE milk_type WHEN 'coconut' THEN 'Vegan' END)" ))->get();
```

I am thinking it has something to do with the ""in the muffin type. The muffin_type is a varchar(255). Does anyone have a clue because I am very perplexed. Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the relationship between `muffins` and `blueberrymuffin`? And specify Model names as well.(Model code)

Comment: What's wrong with that quote? `DB::raw"(CASE`

Answer (score 0):

If a string contains forward slashes, those should be escaped:

```
DB::raw("(CASE muffin_type WHEN 'App\\Models\\blueberrymuffin' THEN 'Blueberry' END)")
```

Pls also have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490325/how-to-handle-a-query-with-special-characters-forward-slash-and-backslash).